# Carousel with slides depending on dynamic list items amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of tags using `ul` and `li` that are being shown in a menu.
This menu must to have a fixed height but the amount of tags is dynamic, when a tag is clicked this tag is removed from that menu.
I need to make some kind of horizontal slide based on the tags i have.
Something like this:

```
         First slide             Second slide
| [tag1] [tag2] [tag3]  | [tag9] [tag10] [tag11] |
| [tag4] [tag5longName] > [tag12reallyLongName]  <
| [tag6] [tag7] [tag8]  |                        |
```

but i don't know how to doit.
I have tried with bootstrap carousel but my problem is that if i remove for example tag4, the carousel must rearrange to put a tag of the second slide on the fist slide.

The html without the slides is here https://jsfiddle.net/Phoenix_uy/DTcHh/19689/

Is this possible?

Comment: I think the reason your question hasn't gotten a lot of attention is because it's not terribly clear what you're trying to do. If I follow, you have two problems: 1) You want tags distributed across "slides"; 2) You want to remove tags and have the remaining tags appropriately redistributed. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.. that's correct